# Difference between Err.Raise and Error.Raise in VB6

Tags: vb6, difference

I am supporting an old VB6 application and I wonder why the code uses both Err.Raise and Error.Raise.  Both appear in the validations after each database call.

We are migrating this application to C#, and I'm trying to understand the subtle difference between these statements in order to correctly reproduce the both behaviors in C#.

I spent quite a few hours searching for information on Error.Raise, and did not find anything useful.

Thanks,

Yves

Comment: There's no built in Error.Raise but you can create a ErrObject called Error, which is most likely the case in your code. Right click on Error and click Definition and see where it brings you.

Comment: When I click Definition, it refers to VB6 libraries.  It's defined in VBA.Conversion, it's a function taking an error number as argument and returns the error message for a given error number.  Maybe the VB6 compiler just substitutes Error.Raise by Err.Raise ???

Comment: If you create a new empty VB6 project there will be no object named  `Error` at all. This may be something introduced in your specific project. I would find an example of it, right click on `Error` and select `Definition` and see where that leads.

Comment: Using Error.Raise, without defining an object called Error, would result in a "Object Required" error. Maybe update your question with some relevant code. Not sure if it will help but it might.

Comment: @Marc You're right.  Inside an On Error Goto block, if some something wrong appears, we call Error.Raise. VB6 branches to the error block to write what went wrong to the log.  In the log we find "Object Required".  It has been there for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Marc was right.  Error.Raise is just wrong.

Calling "Error.Raise 1234" within the scope of an On Error Goto statement will branch to the error block with Err.number = 424 and Err.Description = "Object required".

The solution becomes obvious : replace Error.Raise by Err.Raise everywhere.